# Clicking on the link with the webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

The underlying code, choose the word you want. I wrote these words I want to click on the link. Words may be wrong, so I use Google Translator. Only the "range" values ​​statement how to click? Thank you.

```
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
                IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
                if (document != null)
                {
                    IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;

                    IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
                    if (range != null)
                    {
                        const String search = "Sayfalar";

                        if (range.findText(search, search.Length, 2))
                        {
                            range.select();

                        }
                    }
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the form you just need to know the id of the submit button

VB.NET

```
For Each html As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement In  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            If html.InnerText = "YOUR TEXT" Then
                html.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
Next
```

C#

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement html in WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")) {
    if (html.InnerText == "YOUR TEXT") {
       html.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Contact if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks but i dont want class id or submit id. I need word.

Sample; Meherzad word if i see automatic i want to click this link. But i dont want click all link class or id=user.

and is not a button. @Meherzad

Comment: Thanks again but now giving error.
Code:
 webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("TextToSearch");
                    (0).InvokeMember("click");

Error:
'int' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeMember' and no extension method 'InvokeMember' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

thanks again!

Comment: Yes? And doesnt work because (0).InvokeMember("click"); <- its doesnt work.

Comment: if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
      webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("Sayfalar"); 
                [0].InvokeMember("click");
            } now code is this, but again doesnt work..

Comment: Its vb.net code. You can use converter which are availabe online    http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you asking here. is you asking for webbrowser automation using C# ?

here is sample of clicking with mshtml :

```
using mshtml;

var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("q");
  ((IHTMLElement)element.DomElement).click();
```

ps. Alexander Kent wrote great article about webbrowser automation using C#
, you can find it [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply,

Clicking on the word I want what I want to link. This is how you can select and click on the word? I did something about the process of selecting the code above.